# Switching between two power sources with two NMOS FETs

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, power-electronics, design, mosfet-driver

I need to create a test setup to do a long-term overvoltage test on a device.  The specifications that need to comply with are given below:

[image: Test Specifications]

As you can see, I need a rise and fall time below three microseconds, and I don't have a power supply that can do that. I tried to do that by using two separate power sources. The first will have 36 V, and the second will have 24V. To switch between the two power supplies in under 3 microseconds, I planned to use NMOS. I made the circuit below as a reference. As the ID current will not exceed 150mA, I chose 1N4148 as a diode for reverse polarity, but I paralleled three of them to be safe. To give VGS= 0V/5V to the MOSFETs I used an Arduino UNO.

[image: LtSpice circuit that I created]

After examining the circuit, I observed the current at R2, as the figure below illustrates.

[image: Current graph at R2 when the Vdd2 is 36V]

After creating this circuit in a real lab and trying it, I observed a huge voltage drop. I can't read 36V at the Vout where I will put the device which will undergo the test when the 60 min test time comes. But according to LtSpice simulation, there shouldn't be a problem, as the figure below shows.

[image: Vout graph]

I increased Vdd2 until I read 36V at the Vout and set Vdd2 to 60V, but when I do that, the resistor 2(R2) starts to overheat (approximately 170C,) and it will absolutely burn when I start the 60 minute test in the future. I checked the current at the R2, and I read 40mA to 4mA at the multimeter. The 1k ohm resistor I used has a 5W limit, so it should withstand. What did I do wrong? Can you help me?

Here the datasheet for the [IRF540.](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91021/irf540.pdf)

Comment: Link the resistor R2 data sheet. How much current does the device to be tested need to take when connected to Vout - have you factored this in?

Comment: *As the ID current will not exceed 150mA, I chose 1N4148 as a diode for reverse polarity, but I paralleled three of them to be safe.* As the safe/unsafe thing's a concern in your mind, use one diode instead with a suitable current rating and reverse characteristics. That's simple, safe, cheaper and more reliable.

Comment: The current to the load will go through R1 or R2, so there will be a voltage drop over those resistors, depending on the load current.  You should use a "high side" PMOS switch to control the higher voltage, rather than shorting the unwanted supply to Ground.  I think you only need one switch, on the higher voltage, and just leave the lower voltage on, isolated by diodes when the high voltage is enabled.

Comment: If your resistor is really rated at 5W (it would be physically quite large) it is possibly the incorrect value.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use a MOSFET push-pull driver sat between 24 volts and the 36 volt supply like this: -

[image]

A device I can recommend is the [FOD8343](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fod8343-d.pdf) from ON Semi. OK they are about £3.50 from [such places as Farnell](https://uk.farnell.com/search?st=fod8343t) but control is easy; it's just an opto-diode input that can be ground referenced for convenience when driving with a logic signal.

The one above I have used for HV converters and has a 5 kV input-output rating but, there will be others that are cheaper and maybe have only a 1 kV rating. Not that this is hardly applicable here.

I'm suggesting this part because...

- It's easy to implement and easy to drive
- And, maximum propagation delay is 210 ns.
- Rise and fall times are sub 40 ns too.
- 4 amp maximum current drive
- There are dozens of alternatives that can be chosen instead

You need to use series resistance at the input because it uses an IR LED. The data sheet explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with a single high-side switch as @Peter suggests:

[image]

As you can see, the rise and fall times are << 1usec. If the load can be modeled as a resistance in parallel with a capacitor, the fall time will be longer, but so long as the C is single-digit nF you should be okay.

I used a BJT because driving the gate of a p-channel MOSFET that quickly is a bit harder. D1 is not strictly necessary but it avoids having to sequence the power supplies to avoid damage.

Answer (score 0):

### Specs

Imax 150 mA (steady state or transient?)
Vcc= 24 to 36 V for 1 h
Tr=Tf= <3 us  ( depends on DUT capacitance and source R)

### Simple solution

- only a power diode and switch required.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKk0U4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

RC or Z Snubbers may be required to suppress the inductive Turn off voltage on SW1 (perhaps) to protect 36V supply (unknown quality)

Answer (score 0):

This remained unanswered: "I checked the current at the R2, and I read 40mA to 4mA at the multimeter. The 1k ohm resistor I used has a 5W limit, so it should withstand. What did I do wrong? Can you help me?"

You need to have a heat sink connected to the resistor. Most power resistors specified for a certain power need a heat sink.

Comment: Ralph as per my comment directly under the question (`Link the resistor R2 data sheet`), we are waiting for the OP to provide details. I suspect it might be a SMD resistor too so maybe your answer might be a little incorrect in assuming it is a heatsink mountable one.

Comment: Thanks, yea, I don't know why I put such detailed answer. I'll edit to a more generic one.